Proyecto Hibernate ORM con Maven InteLLij-Idea no compila
Estoy cambiando un proyecto para implementarlo con ORM por un proyecto de clases pero he tenido dos problemas que persisten, el primero es con "is not mapped from hibernate" pero intentando solucionarlo me di cuenta que necesitaba cambiar a JDK 17 o superior y ahora tengo problemas que ni me permiten ejecutarlo, he intentado agregar las dependencias en pom.xml y sin éxito
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.nullpointer.repositories.dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:35)
    at org.nullpointer.controller.ExcursionController.<init>(ExcursionController.java:14)
    at org.nullpointer.view.excursiones.MenuExcursiones.<init>(MenuExcursiones.java:10)
    at org.nullpointer.view.MainMenu.<init>(MainMenu.java:11)
    at org.nullpointer.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createMappingBinderAccess(Configuration.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:174)
    at org.nullpointer.repositories.dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 9 more```


